# Malloc and strncpy

Tags: c, malloc, strncpy

I am trying to split a string in two to pass to two children. the first part should be 12 '0' characters and the second should be 13 '1' characters. When I execute this code, I do not get either of these things. specifically this is the output.
Parent Left: 00000000000
Parent Right: 0000000000001
I have no idea why, can someone help?

```
int bit_count(char *passed, int len){
int left = len/2;
int right =(len/2)+(len % 2);
char *lstring = malloc(sizeof(char)*(left+1));
char *rstring = malloc(sizeof(char)*(right+1));
strncpy(lstring, passed, sizeof(char)*12);
strncpy(rstring, passed+left, sizeof(char)*13);
printf("Parent Left: %s\n", lstring);
printf("Parent Right: %s\n", rstring);
```

Comment: why calculate left and right if you are just gonna hardcode 12 and 13 here. It makes no sense.

Comment: right, I changed it to that just to try to understand what was happening. eventually I will user left and right.

Comment: You don't need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` -- the argument to `strncpy` is the number of characters to copy, not a size.

Comment: @Barmar, the second part of your comment is a bit misleading. Number of `char` and "size" in C are the same thing.

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm trying to distinguish it from how one uses `malloc()`, where one multiples the number of things by the size of each thing to get the size argument. The argument to `strncpy` is not a number of _things_, it's specifically the number of characters to copy.

Comment: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `strncpy` if you don't need it and if you don't know exactly what it does.

In your case it is completely superfluous, you know the size of the array that you want to copy, anyhow. So use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(lstring, passed, left);
lstring[left] = '\0';
memcpy(rstring, passed+left, right);
rstring[right] = '\0';
```

Comment: "Don't use `strncpy` if you don't need it and if you don't know exactly what it does." The same could be said of *any* function. But yes, `strncpy` is particularly misleading.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, and you're right, I don't understand strncpy. Maybe someday.

Comment: A very nice explanation of the [`strncpy()` function](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `strncpy()` doesn't add a null terminator if it stops because of the limit rather than reaching the end of the source string. So you need to add the null terminator.

```
int bit_count(char *passed, int len) {
    int left = len/2;
    int right = len - left;
    char *lstring = malloc(left+1);
    char *rstring = malloc(right+1);
    strncpy(lstring, passed, left);
    lstring[left] = '\0';
    strncpy(rstring, passed+left, right);
    rstring[right] = '\0';
    printf("Parent Left: %s\nParent Right: %s\n", lstring, rstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add NULL character after each strncpy**

```
lstring[left]='\0';


rstring[right]='\0';
```